# CouchDB for event sourcing

Tags: couchdb, event-sourcing, cloudant

I've been playing with CouchDB for a week now and I love it; it's probably the most convenient NoSQL DB I've seen so far.

Now I'm considering using it (Cloudant, actually) to manage entities in an event sourcing fashion, but I have doubts that CouchDB is actually suitable for such a case...

Let's say I want to manage a "type" whose "projection" would be something like:

```
{
    "field1":"some-string",
    "field2":["an","array","of","strings"]
}
```

I would insert events like:

```
{ "type":"set-field1", "value":"another-string" }
{ "type":"remove-field2", "value":"strings" }
{ "type":"add-field2", "value":"bugs" }
```

and as you guess, I would expect the "projection" to become:

```
{
    "field1":"another-string",
    "field2":["an","array","of","bugs"]
}
```

Now I'm still a noob in map/reduce, but my intuition is that:

- the reduce would have to be some pretty elaborate JS and all the docs I've read strongly recommend to use the built-ins reduce functions exclusively
- even though the map is executed incrementally on objects being added/updated (and somehow deleted), I guess that the reduce is always executed on the full output of the map, which makes the previous point even worse...

That's where I am right now. The only thing I've found concerning CouchDB in an event sourcing approach is [this article](http://docs.cloudant.com/guides/eventsourcing.html) (which only uses the built-in _sum reduce, of course!). So I would appreciate any advises/opinions from CouchDB power users about the relevance of my (modest) analysis.

Thanks

Comment: Did you have a look at "[lists](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/couchapp/ddocs.html#listfun)" in order to reformat your "view"?

Comment: Yes lists look handy but it seems that they could only help for the "field2" of my example. Unless I can aggregate its output later down the chain, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: Well, if your view is sorted by object and event time, it shouldn't be so hard to construct resulting objects...